# iTunes slow movie download and does not resume after paused playback

Tags: macos, itunes, itunes-store, movie

iTunes 12.1.0.50 on OS X 10.8.5 MacBook Air is showing weird behavior recently. When I rent a movie from the iTunes store I have the following problems:

1. download is incredibly slow (ETA keeps going up to several hours) and
2. the movie will freeze when I unpause movie playback.

iTunes is basically unusable in this state. Did you ever come across a similar problem? Any ideas how to solve it?

What I tried so far (will update):

- [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) system cleanup
- Re-download re-install iTunes

Comment: more likely to be your network setup - are you wired or wifi? If WiFi, do you have QoS & WMM switched on at your router?

Comment: On Wifi and both are active. Also my other MBP on Yosemite now is affected. I did not change my network setup...

Comment: not a permanent fix, but a possibility - power-cycle the modem/router/AP, if you haven't done yet. Most of them have a brain the size of a peanut & get 'too full of information' after a while, in true Homer Simpson style.

Comment: :D Yeah. A couple of times already...